# why am i getting null in mongoose findOne

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

this is my request -

```
interface IGetFullnameRequest extends IAuthenticatedRequest {
    readonly body: Readonly<{
        fullname: string;
    }>;
}
```

this is my controller -

```
const getFullname = async (req: IGetFullnameRequest, res: IGetFullnameResponse) => {

    const userByFullname: Omit<IUserDocument, 'fullname'
    > | null = await UserDB.findOne({ fullname: req.body.fullname });

    console.log(userByFullname);
}
```

i am getting null - anyone know why?

Comment: Presumably because there is not one that can be returned by findOne.

Comment: @mkrieger1 what do you mean?

Comment: findOne suppedly returns some value matching a condition. If there is no value matching the condition, what should it return? I guess it returns null then.

Comment: @mkrieger1 can you please explain in code what my problem is?

Comment: I think there is no problem in your code, only in your understanding.

Comment: I don't know how else I should explain it to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a function inside of the `findOne` method to get results,

```
await UserDB.findOne({ fullname: req.body.fullname }, function(err, result) { ... });
```

Simply, replace your code with the above one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.